# Getting Image Url using Jsoup

Tags: java, android, image, jsoup, src

I am using jSoup to extract information from the html of a website. But I am facing a problem in fetching data in following case.Html I am working with contains one portion as below and I want to get all those image url

```
<ul class="myClass">
   <li>
      <a>
          <img src="myImageSrc1.png"/>
      </a>
   </li>

   <li>
      <a>
          <img src="myImageSrc2.png"/>
      </a>
   </li>

</ul>
```

I am using somewhat as below:

```
doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.myUrl").get();
castsImageUrl = doc.select("ul.cast > li > a > img");
for (Element el : castsImageUrl)System.out.println(el.text());
```

But I am getting nothing. I can not figure out my problem . Can anyone fix it for me please

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based off the exact HTML you provided, you can extract the image urls by calling the `attr(String key)` method and passing in `src` (see [docs](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/attributes-text-html)). Example:

```
    String html = "<ul class='myClass'><li><a><img src='myImageSrc1.png'/></a></li><li><a><img src='myImageSrc2.png'/></a></li></ul>";
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);

    Elements castsImageUrl = doc.select("ul.myClass > li > a > img");
    for (Element el : castsImageUrl) System.out.println(el.attr("src"));
```

Which outputs:

```
11-06 09:45:11.313: I/System.out(454): myImageSrc1.png
11-06 09:45:11.313: I/System.out(454): myImageSrc2.png
```